# Level curves and trajectories.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider $f(x,y)=(a(x^2+y),3x^4+3x^2y)\; \{a>0\}$ and the system $(x',y')=f(x,y).$ If $H(x,y)=x^n-y,n\in\mathbb{N}$ find $a,n$ in order to make the level curves of $H$ contain the trajectories of the system.

I'm not very familiar solving non-linear system of differential equations. From the system as it is I got the equilibrium points

$$x'=0\iff a(x^2+y)\iff y=-x^2\\y'=0\iff3x^4+3y^2=0\iff x^2y=-1 \:(x\neq 0)\\\text{Equilibrium points: }(0,0),(1,-1),(-1,-1)$$

but I'm not sure if it will be hepful.The goal is to find $a,n$ such that the trajectories of the system are in the level curves of $H$, I thought that finding the equilibrium points would be useful if I could find the equilibria of each point and picture the solution near it (maybe a Lyapunov function could help to find the equilibria?).

Still, how can I find $a,n$ if I don't know explictly the trajectories. If the trajectories are going to be in the level curves of $H$, then they will be the solution of $x^n-y=k$ for some $k$. Then should I try to find a general solution for $x^n(t)=y(t)+k$? (which tried, didn't go well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal direction of the level curves of $H$ is given at any point by
$$
grad\ H(x,y) = (nx^{n-1},-1).
$$
The tangent direction of the trajectories of the given differential equation is given at any point just by
$$
f(x,y).
$$
So a necessary condition that the level curves of $H$ contain the trajectories of the differential equation is
$$
\langle grad\ H(x,y),f(x,y)\rangle \equiv 0,
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes euclidean scalar product. Now we calculate
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle grad\ H(x,y),f(x,y)\rangle & =
\langle(nx^{n-1},-1),(a(x^2+y),3x^4+3x^2y\rangle \\
& =
anx^{n+1}+nax^{n-1}y-3x^4-3x^2y.
\end{align*}
$$
This has to vanish identically. This is only possible if we can get exponents and coefficients to match. In particular, we must have
$$
anx^{n+1} = 3x^4\quad and \quad nax^{n-1}y = 3x^2y.
$$
Luckily, both these conditions can be satisfied if we put
$$
n = 3 \quad and \quad a = 1.
$$
Those must be the values you search.